# Can a team member lose Karma?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

Can a team member lose Karma, either by failing the mission or only aborting when they are suffering a Karma penalty because of having greater than 10 Karma?  For instance, if my Karma 12 character loses the mission, does he actually get -1 Karma and end up with 11?  With no clarification, I house rule it to be yes, you can lose Karma for failing.  Makes sense thematically if Karma is something like reputation.

Answer (score 1):

In the game there is no karma loss for losing only a karma reduction for aborting the mission or a reduction if you have to much karma of for the mission you are going on. Due to the random nature of the game it can be very harsh if you can actually lose karma for failing a mission as depending on the luck it can be very easy for a team to either easily crush a game or easily be crushed by the game depending on the obstacles, crossfire cards and black market cards that are drawn during the game. In this game karma is not like reputation but it is experience points which are gained for succeeding in missions and that is something that is not normally lost easily in most games.

Another thing to remember is that if you do lose karma for failing a mission that would put a lot more pressure on any new players who may be 
playing with experienced players as a failure would risk the more experienced player losing valuable upgrades.

Below I have listed the karma [rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/CAT27700_Crossfire_Full%20Rules.pdf?86527a) for the basic mission

> Karma Awards: If the team wins, each runner gets 3 Karma.
>   If the team aborts, and has a successful abort run round, each
>   runner gets 1 Karma. The team can also choose the following
>   bonus challenge options:
>
> › Bring It On!: Flip up one additional obstacle at the start
>   of each Scene: +1 Karma for each runner
>
> › Danger Zone: Start the game with one card in the
>   Crossfire discard: +2 Karma for each runner (In the same
>   game, the team can choose this option up to once for
>   each runner.)
>
> Karma Scaling: Each runner gains the following Karma award
>   or penalty based on how much Karma they have.
>
> CROSSFIRE KARMA SCALING KARMA IN UPGRADES AWARD OR PENALTY
>   0-10 FULL KARMA AWARD
>   11-30 -1 KARMA PENALTY
>   31-50 -2 KARMA PENALTY
>   51-75 -3 KARMA PENALTY
>   EACH ADDITIONAL +25 ADDITIONAL -1 KARMA PENALTY

Comment: I don't know if I agree it's a horrible penalty. My player with 11 karma would drop to 10 if he failed the mission.  I would agree deciding the house rule on this should consider the points you mentioned, especially when it comes to new players and the proper social or diehard tone of the players involved in the game. I don't think we've definitively figured out what the original designers intended, though. Perhaps this needs to go to emailing them.

Comment: @Joey Considering they have karma reduction in the game for higher karma level players and a way to get karma even if you fail along with no mention ever of losing karma I think it is very safe to say it is not intended to ever lose it. Not to mention there are ways to make the mission harder if you want to and harder missions for higher karma players to attempt.